# Can commercial 9v batteries deliver 2 amps?

Tags: batteries

Are these commonly used, cheapish batteries able to deliver 2 Amps of current continiously and safely?

I know that assuming 200mAh capacity the battery will be dead in 6 minutes or so.

Example batteries:

https://www.hepsiburada.com/varta-power-accu-ready-2-use-9v-pil-e-200mah-56722101401-p-OFISVAR56722101401?magaza=infstore&wt_gl=cpc.6803.shop.nelk.ofis-ofis-teknolojileri&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuZDtBRDvARIsAPXFx3B_oZsxHNskuf7E82mbtejUbONWIwsSxC2bBX2XlHX82fS7oRs51XwaArz8EALw_wcB#reviews

https://www.hepsiburada.com/varta-2022-superlife-9v-pil-shrink-p-HBV000002B6KL?magaza=pilstore&wt_gl=cpc.6803.shop.nelk.ofis-ofis-teknolojileri&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuZDtBRDvARIsAPXFx3BOo0VFOX4w69U08zstTlcjGltLX2qWlco37IklfYpOs4wDDT8L-QcaArdfEALw_wcB

Comment: Which size of 9v.  I know of pp3, pp6, pp9.  No doubt there are others.

Comment: @HandyHowie please see my edit

Comment: At least in the UK when someone talks about a 9V battery without further qualification they almost certainly mean a PP3. When I look for a PP6 I can only find one manufactuer and they want about £15 per battery. PP9s seem to be a bit more available but are still nowhere near as common as PP3s.

Comment: @PeterGreen in the US, the terms PP3, PP6, and PP9 are all but unheard of; they're just called 9V batteries. (or rarely, as a case of hypercorrection, 9V cells)

Comment: https://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm

Comment: @Hearth that is pretty true in the UK too, but the PP6 and PP9 batteries themselves are also "all but unheard of".

Comment: @PeterGreen PP6 and PP9 batteries are unfamiliar here too, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some data here: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Battery-internal-resistance

The maximum output current is the short circuit current. For example for a 9-V alkaline, this maximum output current would be (9V)/(2 Ohms) = 4,5A.

But the actual delivered current will depends of course on your load. You could force a 9-V alkaline to deliver 2A, but because of the internal resistance you would have a 4 volts voltage drop on the internal resistance, and only 5 volts would be supplied to your load.

Edit: this is a theoretical answer. In practice, the battery would get very hot and may even explode. It would probably damage the battery and more important, it could harm you.

Comment: And getting 2 Amps continiously will not harm the battery, right?

Comment: @muyustan I am not sure because I know batteries only from the electronic point of view and not from the chemical point of view.

However, in my opinion, it would be really dangerous and you should not doing it with the batteries you linked. The battery would have to dissipate a lot of power (8W): it will get very hot and could even explode . Do not forget that there is a bunch of chemicals in there.

Comment: You will have a power loss of 4V*2A=8W in your battery. If you do this for just some nano or microseconds the heat should not be a problem. But if you plan to consume power over several seconds, the battery will get pretty warm and also as you mentioned in your question be empty very fast. Please specify why you would use so much current at once if it is to create a pulse a small circuit pumping up some capacitors may be the better way.

Comment: furthermore, the battery will be quite certainly harmed in kind of a chemical way but I'm unsure about that.

Answer (score 4):

No. A common 9V PP3 battery, whether alkaline or NiMH or zinc-carbon, cannot provide anywhere near this much current. Get a different power supply.

Comment: What is the maximum current can be taken by them? For the exact type, pleae see my edit.

Comment: That depends on how much voltage drop you can tolerate. I wouldn't use them for more than 100mA as a general rule of thumb, though.

Comment: by voltage drop do you mean due to internal resistance of the battery? Thanks anyway, your answer helped.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: if you consider the answer below from Wheatley; If I sacrifice 4 volts, can I get continious 2A flow?

Comment: @muyustan No. Your battery would get hot, fast, and may well burst into flame.

Answer (score 1):

9 volt snap-terminal batteries are notoriously wimpy, both for the power they can supply and for the energy they can store for the volume.

I presume you want 2A at 9V, meaning that you *really* want 18W.  You probably aren't going to get that from an equivalent volume of dry-cell batteries at all (1A is a lot to ask from a D cell).

If you can be flexible in the form factor and volume, I'd suggest you try to find some NiMH AA cells that'll deliver 10A, use a pair of them and step the voltage up to 9V.  Or use a single- or two-cell LiPo pack, accept that charging and safety will be a concern, and build a circuit around that.  You ought to be able to find a suitable battery that won't be much bigger than a 9V that will deliver the power you need.

Answer (score 1):

The only widely available batteries in the PP3 form factor that would come close to being able to deliver 2 A would be the primary lithium cells such as Energizer's L522 or UltraLife's U9VLJP. These are only rated for 1 A max continuous discharge and have (different) internal overcurrent protection devices, but for short periods or maybe continuously at lower ambient temperatures you could probably extract 2 A. The terminal voltage would drop to around 5 V.

Answer (score 0):

For a few fractions of a second probably. But it depends a lot on battery state, and probably brand and quality of battery. Basically it is down to internal resistance under sustained near short circuit which I would not like to make any bets on.